# where do you keep track of interesting articles?

Tags: repository, knowledge-management

Like many developers I read alot of articles of different code methodologies, patterns, blogs, examples etc etc along with trailing through github, codeplex etc for code samples.

I have used delicious bookmarks in the past to keep track of interesting articles and sometimes code snippets & repos. However this isnt working very well for me as I keep forgetting and also find it difficult to find articles in there.

So I am wondering what do others use to keep track of above? Would be interested to hear other developers opinions on knowledge and resource management?

Answer (score 1):

i use my blog - http://www.acooke.org/cute - which is generated by email, so this is pretty much equivalent to sending myself an email with the URL, a useful title, and perhaps some commentary.  one advantage of a blog approach is that occasionally people send useful commentary (isn't posterous an email-generated blog?  that would be equivalent...)

i have also used a local install of mediawiki (the wiki that wikipedia is based on, but really any wiki would do - i chose that one so that it wouldn't become obsolete).  but that's better suited to long-term things like clients, details of projects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Google email account
2. Create folder called code collection
3. Create filter for all emails received with subject "code collection" get placed into that folder
4. Find a bit of code you like? or even copy and paste the whole page into an email and send it to yourself with the title "code collection"

Then after time and accumilation of emails in that folder, you will be able to search your emails by the "code collection" folder for keywords - in effect your own personal google searchable code archive.

I been doing this GMail was released and built up a very nice repository of code over 3000 emails spanning lots of languages.

I also keep archives of all work projects, including creative and often make markers on backups to keep certain classes / functions.